# compare a string to a cell array of srings in matlab and find the most similar

Tags: string, search, matlab

I have a list of images stored in a directory. They are all named. My GUI reads all the images and saves their names in a cell array. Now I have added a editable box that the user can type in a name and the program will show that image. The problem is I want the program to take into account typos and misspellings by the user and find the most similar file name to the user typed word. Can you please help me?

Many Thanks,

Hamid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read this WP article: [Approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and look at "[Calculation of distance between strings](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17585-calculation-of-distance-between-strings)" on [FEx](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange).

Comment: @hamidzolfaghari, if that is exactly what you wanted, accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the longest common subsequence algorithm to approximately compare strings.

Here is a matlab implementation:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24559-longest-common-subsequence

After, just do something like that:

```
[~,ind]=min(cellarray( @(x) LCS(lower(userInput),lower(x)), allFileNames));
chosenFile=allFileName{ind};
```

(the function `LCS` is the longest common subsequence algorithm, and the function`lower` converts to lower case)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you can compare the first few characters of the strings ignoring case to find a close match.  See the command strncmpi:

> strncmpi Compare first N characters of strings ignoring case.
>
> TF = strncmpi(S,C,N) performs a case-insensitive comparison between the
> first N characters of string S and the first N characters in each element
> of cell array C. Input S is a character vector (or 1-by-1 cell array), and
> input C is a cell array of strings. The function returns TF, a logical
> array that is the same size as C and contains logical 1 (true) for those
> elements of C that are a match, except for letter case, and logical 0
> (false) for those elements that are not. The order of the two input
> arguments is not important.

Comment: Thanks Kavka, although helpful but the problem is that the code will get stuck at instances such as "Thanks" and "Thursday". Besides, it doesnt take into account misspellings on the first couple of letters. Thanks anyway